# Why does Mozilla Firefox page refresh after javascript alert button clicked?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am running a Java web application and want to use Mozilla Firefox. The user of the program clicks a button in the java application, which brings up a javascript alert displaying some information. The user then clicks the alert's "okay" button to close the alert and carry on using the program.

The java script is defined:

`<td><button onclick="myFunction(<c:out
                                    value="${current.regradeId}" />)"><c:out
                                    value="${current.regradeId}" /></button>`

where current.regradeID is an integer from 1 to 199

Example of js code:

`function myFunction(x) {
    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        alert("No data")
        break;
    case 2:...`.

When running on IE9 the program runs correctly. But in firefox, when the "okay" button on the alert is clicked, the whole firefox page refreshes.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to stop it?

Thank you

**Update

I fixed the problem by using a href instead of a button. The code is below. The page now does not refresh on IE and firefox when the alert box is closed.

```
<td><a href="javascript:void myFunction(<c:out
                                value="${current.regradeId}" />)"><c:out
                                value="${current.regradeId}" /></a>
```

Comment: Without seeing the exact code causing the issue no, we can't say why.

Comment: because the button submits the page. Cancel the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the alert You can use return false; to stop further execution.

Answer (score 0):

buttons submit forms, it's default behaviour. Just add type="button".